# Variable name declaration for key in associative array

Tags: javascript, debugging, syntax, web

I am operating inside of a javascript `for()` loop and need to produce the following dynamically:

```
devCssFiles[ '../'+thisTheme._name+'/assets/css/main.css' ] = 
'child_themes/'+thisTheme._name+'/master.less';
```

the intended result is an associative array that can be declared iteratively inside of a parent object, e.g.  (`thisTheme._name` is declared in an external JSON file which is read when the code below is processed, this part is working fine)

```
var myConfigObj = {};

for ( var key in thisThemeMetaObj ) {
   var devCssFiles = [],
      devCssFiles[ '../'+thisTheme._name+'/assets/css/main.css' ] = 
   'child_themes/'+thisTheme._name+'/master.less'; 
   myConfigObj[thisTheme._name] = devCssFiles;
}
```

I'm trying to give a complete explanation, but the problem is quite simple, I'm just declaring the named key of the associative array incorrectly at the line which reads `devCssFiles[ '../'+thisTheme._name+'/assets/css/main.css' ] =     'child_themes/'+thisTheme._name+'/master.less';`

Can someone show me the correct syntax here?

The intended output should be a JSON object like this:

```
    myConfigObject: {
        '../themeFoo/assets/css/main.css': [
            'child_themes/themeFoo/master.less'
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Note that I've left out declarations of some of the variables in the explanation in the interest of being concise, since I understand the system (it's pretty complex) and I just need to know how to dynamically name the array keys in the `for()` loop, the rest of it is all working fine.

Comment: Why don't you use the `key` variable inside the `for` loop? If you intend using a "named key" (i.e., non-numeric indices) you should say `devCssFiles = {}` to use an object rather than an array. But either way your code should be creating a property with a name equal to the result of the expression `'../'+thisTheme._name+'/assets/css/main.css'`.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error was here:

```
var devCssFiles = [],
      devCssFiles[ '../'+thisTheme._name+'/assets/css/main.css' ] = 
   'child_themes/'+thisTheme._name+'/master.less';
```

Problem being that `devCssFiles = []` needs a semicolon (rather than a comma) so that the variable is in existence when the variable named property is declared.  So it should be

```
var devCssFiles = [];
   devCssFiles[ '../'+thisTheme._name+'/assets/css/main.css' ] = 
   'child_themes/'+thisTheme._name+'/master.less';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
var myConfigObj = {};
for ( var key in thisThemeMetaObj ) {
   var thisTheme = thisThemeMetaObj[key],
       devCssFiles = [ 'child_themes/'+thisTheme._name+'/master.less' ]; // array literal
   myConfigObj['../'+thisTheme._name+'/assets/css/main.css'] = devCssFiles;
}
```

Notice that your `devCssFiles` was an array but you did create a non-numeric property on it.